# UpdateExpression Increment value of nested map within list

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table structure:

```
{myHashKey: x, someList: [{info: uniqueID, myAttribute: number, ...}, ...]}
```

I'd like to increment `number`, for a given `info` sub-attribute.
ie, say I have the following item inserted in dynamodb:

```
{myHashKey: 'xxxx', someList: [{info: 'a', myAttribute: 1}, {info: 'b', myAttribute: 42}]}
```

What UpdateExpression would I have to perform in order to update the item to increment the myAttribute for a given info by a given number, say I want to increment the myAttribute `1` of info `a` to `5`, ie get from the above to this:

```
{myHashKey: 'xxxx', someList: [{info: 'a', myAttribute: 5}, {info: 'b', myAttribute: 42}]}
```

?

I read a bunch of docs and other stackoverflow posts but still can't achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot efficiently target the item in the list to update. I do not think it is possible with your table structure. I had some time ago the same issue, but I didn't found a solution. I've change may table structure.

I guess your table is not well designed for what you want to do. DynamoDB is a column database, make use of it.

Table suggestion:

- Hash: `myHashKey` // the same as now
- Range: `info`
  other fields `myAttribute`

When you know `myHashKey` and `info` you may easily find and update.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function async increment(myHashKeyValue, infoValue, value = 1) {

    var params = {
        TableName:table,
        Key:{
            "myHashKey": myHashKeyValue,
            "info": infoValue,
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set #myAttribute = #myAttribute + :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":val": value,
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames:{
            '#myAttribute': 'myAttribute',
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    await docClient.update(params).promise();
});
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, with such a structure, would I not have many many many near-duplicates of my objects? Say my someList list would contain 10000 items on average, wouldn't that make me have 10000 nearly-identical items in my database that essentially model the same thing, therefore cluttering it? What if I just want access to the other attributes of my item, that don't depend on `info`, how would I query them, since querying hashKey only now gives me back a lot of items?

Comment: With `get` you may only get one item by using both partition key and sorting key. With `query` you may get more items, by using a partition key and conditioning the sorting key. You can do whatever you want: • you can get one precise item you want • you can get a range of items you want • you can get all items for a partition key • you can retrieve all items in the database (with a scan). It is your choice! :)

Comment: thanks for answering. The thing though is that if I put `info` (so my currently nested attribute) as range key, I will only know it in very few cases - ie, when I just want the other attributes, I will most likely *not* know the range key at that time. I only know the range key when I want to achieve what I described above, and not in all other situations. So by simply querying on the hashkey, I would use up a whole lot more data volume than needed. Or  I guess I could just limit by one or something, but it still doesn't sit quite right with me how full the table will easily get, though?

Comment: As long as I do not know your whole case I cannot advice you a solution that fits all the conditions. Based on your latest post I can recommend you to create a second table, with the same partition key, that holds all the elements without an 'info' information. Or for the items without info you may randomly invent one: 'unknown0', 'unknown1', etc. Thus you will be able to make your queries. • With NoSQL, always start your design by preparing the queries: "What are the questions I need to answer? Then, how will I answer?"